# Scrollable lazy loading table in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, lazy-loading, flexbuilder

I need to implement a lazy loading table in FLEX i.e load the table data once user starts scrolling down.

Something like this : http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf?c=scrollableDataTable&tab=usage

Is there a ready made component available in FLEX to handle such requirement. If so can I have a look of that in any FLEX showcase or demo site?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 0):

Its sometimes referred to as data-paging. James Wards has a very good demo is on Tour De Flex under Flex 4.5 for a DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no, there are no default components that does this behavior out of the box.  However, you can code it.  Since the DataGrid is data driven, you can update the dataProvider property with new data when the user scrolls to the bottom of the DataGrid.  You'll need to figure that out on your own.

However, this behavior is not something I would agree with from a User Experience standpoint.  I would seek another way for the user to get to the data they want, like pagination, loading all the data at once (if possible), maybe have a searching functionality or filtering.  It really depends what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Achso, I definitely implemented pagination as well as searching. The search result is again expected to be very huge and also users would appreciate lazy loading instead of pagination. So wanted to go for this absurd combination of search as well as lazy loading of table...

Comment: But never the less I would prefer to go for JQuery to achieve this lazy loading of the table...hope users aslo like this solution

Comment: With BlazeDS or ZendAMF in Flash Builder 4, you can set up your project to run Data Services, and choose Data Paging as an option (thats out of the box stuff) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_datapaging_php.html

Answer (score 0):

Two example for lazy loading for Flex 4:

http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/11/data-paging-in-flex-4/

http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/10/26/infinitely-scrolling-lists-in-flex-applications/